# Integration test before others

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

I have a bunch of integration tests that need to have a database populated before running. This task takes about 30 minutes, so it is not feasible to run it before every test.

I'm using junit and I'd like to be able to annotate this one class with something so that it runs and completes before the others start. Is this possible?

(most of the annotations I found only work on methods, e.g. @Rule)

Comment: I think integration test is not supposed to test your entire populated data. An integration test should generally create its own test data at the beginning and clean them up after test finishs. An integration test that replies on pre-populated data is very hard to maintain. I think you just need to have your schema constructed and each test should create its own, small data set for its own use and clean them up after test finishes.

Comment: @KZhang this is the minimal set of data needed to do the tests and it is not possible to do what you're saying for a variety of reasons (I do what you're saying when it is possible... indeed see the akka-patterns contribution I made for Scala fixtures that do exactly this).

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past by adding setup and teardown functions to the individual test classes, annotated with `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupBeforeClass() {
    DatabasePopulater.populate();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() {
    DatabasePopulater.dePopulate();
}
```

If more than one test class requires the same setup to be done, the setup function can do a kind of reference counting to make sure they only do their work the first time it's called:

```
public class DatabasePopulater {
    AtomicInteger invocations = new AtomicInteger();
    ....

    public static void populate() {
        if (0 == ivocations.getAndIncrement()) {
            // Actually populate DB
        }
    }

    public static void dePopulate() {
        if (0 == ivocations.decrementAndGet()) {
            // Actually clear DB
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing (from an abstract class that all integration tests inherit from)... I'm looking for something cleaner that doesn't involve managing concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like ant/gradle to execute the test suite, you could separate out the db population into a standalone java program and then have a depends="populateDB" on the junit task.

Comment: thanks. The solution would have to work in IntelliJ, Eclipse and a heavily customised corporate ant framework (of which I have no control over).